Creating a scaleable ImageIcon
I'm trying to create a button with a scaleable image icon – that is, one whose icon is automatically resized along with its parent. Here's my attempt at doing so:
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ScaleableImageIcon extends ImageIcon {

    public ScaleableImageIcon(String path) {
        this(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(path));
    }

    public ScaleableImageIcon(ImageIcon imageIcon) {
        this(imageIcon.getImage());
    }

    public ScaleableImageIcon(Image image) {
        super(image);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        ImageObserver imageObserver = getImageObserver();
        Image scaledImage = getImage().getScaledInstance(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        g.drawImage(scaledImage, x, y, Objects.requireNonNullElse(imageObserver, c));
    }
}

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        String iconImagePath = "delete-icon.png";
        JButton imageButton = new JButton(new ScaleableImageIcon(iconImagePath));
        frame.add(imageButton);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

icon image:

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. No image is visible and generally it looks weird
frame contents are blank, no image:

What is my mistake and how do I achieve my goal?

Check out the Stretch Icon

You probably need to implement Icon rather than extend ImageIcon. The latter already has an Icon embedded within the object itself, meaning that your own variable shadow's the super's variable.

I think camickr's stretch icon is probably a better go to solution, you might also consider having a look at something like this if you want some idea of rolling your own

@HovercraftFullOfEels on the other hand, StretchIcon does extend ImageIcon
